# Highlight links an corresponding images on hover

Tags: jquery, hover

Working on a project an need a specific effect on the homepage. When a user hovers over the links in the nav the link is highlighted as well as the corresponding thumbnail on the page. Each of the links/thumbnails have classes an how we have it setup now is that on hover we search for the the element with the same class. Just wondering if there is a better way to go about doing this. Thanks.

(The layout of the page has the links on the left side an the thumbs in the "main" container which fills out that rest of the page)

```
$('#homeCatNav li a, #homeThumbsUlHolder li img').hover(function(e){
    var $thisA = $(this),
        $thisClass = $(this).attr("class");

    if (e.type.toLowerCase() === 'mouseenter') {
        $('li.imgToHighlight').find('img'+'.'+$thisClass).addClass('hoverElem');
        $('li.homeArtNameList').find('a'+'.'+$thisClass).addClass('hoverElem');             
    }
    if (e.type.toLowerCase() === 'mouseleave') {
        $('li.imgToHighlight').find('img').removeClass('hoverElem');
        $('li.homeArtNameList').find('a').removeClass('hoverElem');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are complicating the event handler why just do it like this

```
$("'#homeCatNav li a, #homeThumbsUlHolder li img").hover(mouseOver, mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
     $thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
     $('li.imgToHighlight').find('img'+'.'+$thisClass).addClass('hoverElem');
     $('li.homeArtNameList').find('a'+'.'+$thisClass).addClass('hoverElem'); 
}

function mouseOut() {
   $thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
   $('li.imgToHighlight').find('img').removeClass('hoverElem');
   $('li.homeArtNameList').find('a').removeClass('hoverElem');
}
```

Comment: This way the variables are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to "rel", but it doesn't   really matter :

```
$('#homeCatNav li a, #homeThumbsUlHolder li img').hover(function(){
        var $thisA = $(this),
        $thisRel = $thisA.attr("rel");
        $('li.imgToHighlight').find('img[rel'+$thisRel+']').addClass('hoverElem');
        $('li.homeArtNameList').find('a[rel'+$thisRel+']').addClass('hoverElem');             
    },function(){
        $('li.imgToHighlight').find('img').removeClass('hoverElem');
        $('li.homeArtNameList').find('a').removeClass('hoverElem');
});
```

Comment: Any reason in particular to switch to Rel? Just a reference sake or for speed?

Comment: in case you want to use this class in the css, and not to affect both elements,  ex:(homeCatNav and homeArtNameList), will have the same classname, but it is not a huge deal

Comment: Ah yeah, thought about that but since i am just using the names pulled from the DB as the class it should avoid any of those particular situations. Thanks for the input.